The wps pdf reader is not working on Ubuntu 24.04
The wps office pdf reader is not working on Ubuntu 24.04, and apparently the problem is not exclusive to opensuse with gmone 46 as well, I don't know if it is a gmone problem because we are talking about .deb and .rpm

I also encountered this problem, unable to open pdf and unable to convert other files to pdf.
It was found that there is no libtiff.so.5 in Ubuntu 23.04 and Ubuntu 24.04. You can create a symlink to guide to libtiff.so.6
cd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
sudo ln -s libtiff.so.6 libtiff.so.5

